# Pulumi AWS API Gateway: How to create CloudWath Logs for Logs/Tracing in Python?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pulumi, pulumi-python

I use Pulumi with the Python module pulumi_aws_apigateway to create Lambda function and API Gateway. I would like to enable CloudWatch Logs with "Full Request and Response Logs" for Logs/Tracing. I got errors as follows:

```
./__main__.py", line 60, in <module>
        stage_log = apigateway.StageLog('alert-stage-log',
    AttributeError: module 'pulumi_aws_apigateway' has no attribute 'StageLog'
```

As the error states, the module 'pulumi_aws_apigateway' has no attribute 'StageLog'. Is there any another way to connect the API Gateway state to the CloudWatch Log Group?
As follows is my code.

```
import json
import pulumi
import pulumi_aws as aws
from pulumi import export
import pulumi_aws_apigateway as apigateway

IDENTITY_NAME = "alert"

role = aws.iam.Role(
    f"{IDENTITY_NAME}-lambda-role",
    assume_role_policy=json.dumps({
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [{
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": { "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com" },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }]
    })
)

policy = aws.iam.RolePolicy(
    f"{IDENTITY_NAME}-sqs-role-policy",
    role=role.id,
    policy=json.dumps({
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [{
            "Action": ["logs:*", "cloudwatch:*"],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
        },
        {
            "Action": ["sqs:SendMessage"],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
      ],
    })
    )

f = aws.lambda_.Function(
    "alertlambda",
    runtime="python3.9",
    code=pulumi.AssetArchive({
        ".": pulumi.FileArchive("./handler"),
    }),
    timeout=300,
    handler="handler.handler",
    role=role.arn,
    opts=pulumi.ResourceOptions(depends_on=[policy]),
)

api = apigateway.RestAPI(f"{IDENTITY_NAME}api", stage_name="alert", routes=[
    apigateway.RouteArgs(path="/{proxy+}", method="ANY", event_handler=f),
])

# Create a CloudWatch Log Group
log_group = aws.cloudwatch.LogGroup('alert-log-group', name='/aws/api-gateway/alert-api')

# Connect the API Gateway stage to the CloudWatch Log Group
stage_log = apigateway.StageLog('alert-stage-log',
                                rest_api_id=api.id,
                                stage_name="alert",
                                cloudwatch_log_group_arn=log_group.arn)

pulumi.export('url', api.url)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you're creating the log group seems fine, the issue is how you're using the `apigateway`. Try this:

```py
import pulumi
import pulumi_aws as aws
import pulumi_aws.apigateway as apigateway

lg = aws.cloudwatch.LogGroup('alert-log-group',
                             name='alert-api',
                             retention_in_days=30)

stage_log = apigateway.StageLog('alert-stage-log',
                                rest_api_id=api.id,
                                stage_name='alert',
                                cloudwatch_log_group_arn=lg.arn)

pulumi.export('log group', lg.name)
pulumi.export('url', api.invoke_url)
```